# Is there any VPAID client?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, vast

Scenario: Need to play VPAID ads with "In Content" mode, on mobile

Most of the solution I found is either some other players plugin (like videojs) or doesn't support mobile (like google ima)

Or, something like this:
https://github.com/dailymotion/vast-client-js

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with in-content, but I assume that you're looking for a video player that supports VPAID. After all, VPAID does just that, it allows you to create interactive content (e.g. an HTML canvas) that shows within your video ad or even interacts with the video player itself (e.g. pauses the publisher video).

IMA is a perfect plugin for a video player like Video.js and it does support mobile -JavaScript VPAID creatives- (what makes you think that it doesn't?) Hopefully I'll be able to help you further if I know what you're looking for.

Comment: "In content": the video player plays only the ad provided by VPAID, there's no contents other then the ad video. In this scenario there's no need for another player to play the main content since ad video is the only thing needed to be played.

Comment: And yes I ended up using IMA as my solution, the only problem is it can not achieve looping playback of ad video

Comment: I came to the conclusion that with "in content" you mean nonlinear (i.e. an ad that shows over the publisher video). Instead of a VAST linear ad with VPAID, you should use a VAST nonlinear ad with VPAID. That way the video player (you in this case, since you control the video player) can decide when to include your VAST/VPAID ad (which is how the spec is meant to work).